# which changes do from live server to localhost in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I changed in **core_config_data** value to "localhost" but it returns  **Not Found
The requested URL /magento_store/localhost/ was not found on this server.**
also i changed in **env** file but again i face that problem.please explain which changes i do from transfering **live server** to **localhost**

Comment: What is folder name of your magento root dir and what exactely url you have entered ib core_config_data

Comment: ROOT DIR  "var/www/magento_store" and in core_config_data "localhost/magento_store"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by insert row in core_config_data

```
insert into core_config_data  
values( 1,'default', 0 ,' web/seo/use_rewrites',1);
```

By default it missing

Answer (score 0):

To transfer your live site to local server, you have to make below changes -

1. You have to change your base url to `localhost/path_to_your_magento_root` or `127.0.0.1/path_to_your_magento_root`
2. In `env.php` you have to change your database details like below-

> ```
> 'db' => 
>   array (
>     'table_prefix' => '',
>     'connection' => 
>     array (
>       'default' => 
>       array (
>         'host' => 'localhost',
>         'dbname' => 'db_name',
>         'username' => 'db_username',
>         'password' => 'db_password',
>         'active' => '1',
>       ),
>     ),
>   ),
> ```

Comment: localhost = 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: you can add anyone of two, both are similar

Comment: error Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: No host configured to connect

Comment: just do one thing rename your `env.php` and then run your local url in browser it will ask you reinstall the Magento,

Comment: i do it all but error like "error Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: No host configured to connect"

Comment: can you give path , where you have put your Magento folder?

Comment: var/www/magento_store here i store